# How to make fixed column headers for a bootstrap table? Same format

Tags: html, css, html-table, bootstrap-4

I'd like to keep the same style of the current table and add a fixed header. However, I'm having issues with making the header fixed. This page contains 4 tables with similar formatting.

```css
.table-wrapper-2 {
  display: block;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-wrapper-2">

      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed" id="entityTable">
        <thead>
          <tr class="table-primary">
            <th scope="col" style="width: 3%">#</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 19%">ID</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width:19%">Col 1</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 19%">Col 2</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 19%">Col 3</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 19%">Col 4</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let id of transactionId, let i = index" class="clickable-row" (click)="onTransactionIdChange(id)">
            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
            <td>{{id}}</td>
            <td>{{col1[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col2[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col3[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col4[i]}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the `sticky-top` built-in class.

example with the class added to the `tr` of `thead` `<tr class="table-primary sticky-top">`:

```css
.table-wrapper-2  {
  display: block;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x:  auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-wrapper-2">

      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed" id="entityTable">
        <thead>
          <tr class="table-primary sticky-top">
            <th scope="col" style="width: 3%">#</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 19%">ID</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width:19%">Col 1</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 19%">Col 2</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 19%">Col 3</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 19%">Col 4</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let id of transactionId, let i = index" class="clickable-row" (click)="onTransactionIdChange(id)">
            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
            <td>{{id}}</td>
            <td>{{col1[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col2[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col3[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col4[i]}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let id of transactionId, let i = index" class="clickable-row" (click)="onTransactionIdChange(id)">
            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
            <td>{{id}}</td>
            <td>{{col1[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col2[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col3[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col4[i]}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let id of transactionId, let i = index" class="clickable-row" (click)="onTransactionIdChange(id)">
            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
            <td>{{id}}</td>
            <td>{{col1[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col2[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col3[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col4[i]}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let id of transactionId, let i = index" class="clickable-row" (click)="onTransactionIdChange(id)">
            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
            <td>{{id}}</td>
            <td>{{col1[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col2[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col3[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col4[i]}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let id of transactionId, let i = index" class="clickable-row" (click)="onTransactionIdChange(id)">
            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
            <td>{{id}}</td>
            <td>{{col1[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col2[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col3[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col4[i]}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let id of transactionId, let i = index" class="clickable-row" (click)="onTransactionIdChange(id)">
            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
            <td>{{id}}</td>
            <td>{{col1[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col2[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col3[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col4[i]}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let id of transactionId, let i = index" class="clickable-row" (click)="onTransactionIdChange(id)">
            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
            <td>{{id}}</td>
            <td>{{col1[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col2[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col3[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col4[i]}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let id of transactionId, let i = index" class="clickable-row" (click)="onTransactionIdChange(id)">
            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
            <td>{{id}}</td>
            <td>{{col1[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col2[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col3[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col4[i]}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let id of transactionId, let i = index" class="clickable-row" (click)="onTransactionIdChange(id)">
            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
            <td>{{id}}</td>
            <td>{{col1[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col2[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col3[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col4[i]}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let id of transactionId, let i = index" class="clickable-row" (click)="onTransactionIdChange(id)">
            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
            <td>{{id}}</td>
            <td>{{col1[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col2[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col3[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col4[i]}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let id of transactionId, let i = index" class="clickable-row" (click)="onTransactionIdChange(id)">
            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
            <td>{{id}}</td>
            <td>{{col1[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col2[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col3[i]}}</td>
            <td>{{col4[i]}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also take a look at snippets ready made https://www.bootply.com/tagged/sticky